# Reading text that has blank spaces and empty lines

Tags: c, text

I tried to read a text with `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name);` but I can't read empty lines for example a text like this:

```
"aaaa bb


cc bb"
```

I tried to put `"\n"` at the end but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use `fgets` instead, with it you can read every line

Comment: Who or what text suggested `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name);`?

Comment: `scanf` is severely over-rated. Try using low-level functions like `fread` and parse it properly if you're concerned about formatting issues.